# Openness in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis

In metric spaces, if we have a collection of open sets, then their arbitrary union and finite intersection will still be an open set. But is the reciprocal true? If we have a family of sets with the property that their arbitrary union and finite intersection is still in that same family, does that imply they're open in the context of metric spaces? I would expect this to be the case, because if we're trying to extend the notion of openness to topological spaces, it would make sense to choose a condition that is equivalent in a smaller framework. However I can't see anyway of justifying whether it'd be true or not.

Comment: You only get a topology (assuming that the empty set and the whole space are in the collection). Not every topological space is metrizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can take any $A \subseteq X$ that you like, and note that $\{A\}$ is such a family (closed under arbitary unions and finite intersections), or $\{A,B\}$ if we take sets $A \subseteq B$, more generally (any finite chain will do).

Such families can define **a** topology (if we add $\emptyset$ and $X$), but it has nothing do to with any given topology or metric that we started with.

Comment: Also, the full power set (set of subsets) of the given space is always an example.